# Make a JPanel transparent to see behind the frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, translucency

I know how to do a shaped or a translucent `JFrame`, but I would like to have a rectangular zone in my frame which would be translucent so the user can see what is behind.
I don't know how to do that and take a screen capture of what is behind the frame is not working for me, because I want really that the user see dynamical change behind the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I would like to have a rectangular zone in my frame which would be
>   translucent so the user can see what is behind.

- `JFrame` has a `BorderLayout`, `BorderLayout` has 5 areas,
- take this advantage from `BorderLayout`, create a `Translucent JFrame` and leave the `CENTER` area translucent, put an opaque Panel in the the other areas.
- mabye now, there is real reason to mix `AWT` (doesn't support transparency & translucency) with `Swing`, you can put `AWT Panels` to the `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST` and `WEST` areas

> a screen capture of what is behind the frame is not working for me,
>   because I want really that the user dynamical change behind the frame.

- see [Screen Image by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/)

Comment: In my edit I improved _grammar_, auto-correct turned it into **grammatica** which is the Dutch word...